# Custom routing in MVC for certain types of URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect URLs of type:

```
www.mypage.com/news/1.1.2014
www.mypage.com/news/2.2.2014
www.mypage.com/news/3.3.2014
```

to a controller named "News" and action called "Index". Date can be any parameter.

Is this the correct way? (Can't test if it works, since I don't have an MVC application to test it on)

```
name: "News",
url: {controller}/{action}/{date},
defaults: new {controller="News", action="Index" , date=UrlParameter.Optional}

name: "News",
url: News/{action}/{date},
defaults: new {controller="News", action="Index" , date=UrlParameter.Optional}
```

Is any of these the correct way? If not, please assist me. Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I couldn't try it, since I don't have any MCV apllication to go with.

Comment: Go here and select mvc project type: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route needs to be registered as follows:

```
name: "News",
url: "news/{date}",
defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index", date = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Please not that the route has to be registered before any other route than can match the url pattern (including the default/fallback route).